# Is it possible to rewrite url to another domain where the files are not located, using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

A website is located at http://www.siteone.com
and I'd like to rewrite the url to something like http://www.anothersite.com/siteone or to a subdomain http://siteone.anothersite.com.

The website will be hosted only at http://www.siteone.com and no files will be moved or copied to anothersite.com.

Is it possible to do this using .htaccess or is there another way to do this?

EDIT (Below is what I've done in htaccess in my localhost and it does not seem to work). Not sure what I am doing wrong. I don't want to mess with the live site at this stage.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} /localhost/mysite [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.anothersite.com/siteone/$1 [L,P] 
ProxyPassReverse /localhost/mysite http://www.anothersite.com/siteone/
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have **mod_proxy** loaded, you can reverse proxy requests using the `P` flag in a rewrite rule. You can do this inside an htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?siteone.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.anothersite.com/siteone/$1 [L,P]
```

This will make it so when you visit `http://siteone.com/some/path/`, the request will get reverse proxied to `http://www.anothersite.com/siteone/some/path/` and the contents from that request will be sent to the original request. This the URL in one's browser remains `http://siteone.com/some/path/`.

In order to handle things like redirects, you need to set a [ProxyPassReverse](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) so that the location headers get property rewritten:

```
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.anothersite.com/siteone/
```

See also, `ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain` and `ProxyPassReverseCookiePath` if the site at `www.anothersite.com` wants to set cookies.

Note: although the `ProxyPass` directive can only be used in vhost and server config, the `ProxyPassReverse` directives can actually be used in an htaccess file in conjunction with mod_rewrite.

Comment: I guess this is done in htaccess in the original site, right? For this to work, do both the domains have to be hosted by the same host or it does not matter?

Comment: @user1448031 Yes, this needs to be in the htaccess file in the document root of the **siteone.com** site. Both domains don't need ot be hosted on the same host, or even the same network. Just as long as the server that hosts **siteone.com** can access the **anothersite.com** site.

Comment: Not sure if I am doing anything wrong. I tried it in htaccess in my localhost but it does not seem to work. I tried this
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} /localhost/mysite [NC]`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.anothersite.com/siteone/$1 [L,P] `
`ProxyPassReverse /localhost/mysite http://www.anothersite.com/siteone/`

Comment: @user1448031 The `%{HTTP_HOST}` matches the "Host" request field, it has no paths in it, **it is ONLY a hostname**, so it can never have a `/` character or paths in it. See the mod_proxy link that I provided, that is incorrect syntax for `ProxyPassReverse`